# Python: Generate a new array with more columns based on another array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have this array:
[image]

I need create a new array like this:
[image]

I guess I need use a conditional, but I don't know how create an array with 7 columns, based on values of a 5 columns array.

If anyone could help me, I thank!

Comment: You never explained how the last number in the line effects the 0/1 that's being written to the end?

Comment: [np.hstack()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume you want to convert your last column into one hot concodings and then concat it to your original array. You can initialise an array of zeros, and then set the appropriate indices to `1`. Finally concat the OHE array to your original.

---

MCVE:

```
print(arr)  
array([[ -9.95,  15.27,   9.08,   1.  ],
       [ -6.81,  11.87,   8.38,   2.  ],
       [ -3.02,  11.08,  -8.5 ,   1.  ],
       [ -5.73,  -2.29,  -2.09,   2.  ],
       [ -7.01,  -0.9 ,  12.91,   2.  ],
       [-11.64, -10.3 ,   2.09,   2.  ],
       [ 17.85,  13.7 ,   2.14,   0.  ],
       [  6.34,  -9.49,  -8.05,   2.  ],
       [ 18.62,  -9.43,  -1.02,   1.  ],
       [ -2.15, -23.65, -13.03,   1.  ]])

c = arr[:, -1].astype(int)    
ohe = np.zeros((c.shape[0], c.max() + 1))
ohe[np.arange(c.shape[0]), c] = 1   

arr = np.hstack((arr[:, :-1], ohe))

print(arr)
array([[ -9.95,  15.27,   9.08,   0.  ,   1.  ,   0.  ],
       [ -6.81,  11.87,   8.38,   0.  ,   0.  ,   1.  ],
       [ -3.02,  11.08,  -8.5 ,   0.  ,   1.  ,   0.  ],
       [ -5.73,  -2.29,  -2.09,   0.  ,   0.  ,   1.  ],
       [ -7.01,  -0.9 ,  12.91,   0.  ,   0.  ,   1.  ],
       [-11.64, -10.3 ,   2.09,   0.  ,   0.  ,   1.  ],
       [ 17.85,  13.7 ,   2.14,   1.  ,   0.  ,   0.  ],
       [  6.34,  -9.49,  -8.05,   0.  ,   0.  ,   1.  ],
       [ 18.62,  -9.43,  -1.02,   0.  ,   1.  ,   0.  ],
       [ -2.15, -23.65, -13.03,   0.  ,   1.  ,   0.  ]])
```

Comment: Perfect! Very well explained! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

One-line version of @COLDSPEED using the `np.eye` trick:

```
np.hstack([arr[:,:-1], np.eye(arr[:,-1].astype(int).max() + 1)[arr[:,-1].astype(int)]])
```